# 'String?' can not convert to 'String' in dart

Tags: dart

A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.
This error message i got when i run this code.

This is a simple user input code on dart.

```
    var person = ['abc', 'qwe', 'dfg'];
    stdout.write('Enter Index : ');
    String p = stdin.readLineSync(); //Error
    int per = int.parse(p);

    per > person.length
      ? stderr.write('Index does not exist')
      : stdout.write('Person ${person[per]}');
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like `readLineSync()` returns nullable type. But you declare variable `p` as non-nullable. Either declare `p` as nullable: `String?` instead of `String` or make `readLineSync()` return default value if null:

```
String p = stdin.readLineSync() ?? "";// will return empty String if method readLineSync() returns null.
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all check the null safety documentation, you'll learn everything you need to know
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

`readLineSync` returns a value of Type `String?` Meaning the return value must be a nullable String.

`p` is of type `String` and therefore expects a `String` (not a nullable String). the trick here is to cast `stdin.readLineSync()` to `String`:

```
String p = stdin.readLineSync() as String;
String p = stdin.readLineSync()!; #shorthand syntax
```

On top of that, your code needs some improvements. What if `p` can't be cast into an integer? One way to handle this is to add a try block and catch any FormatException.